# Shell shows bunch of error in Azure Devops pipeline although commands succeed

Tags: bash, shell, azure-devops

I am using Azure Devops to build and deploy my git repo to a third party vps. I do this by logging into the server from Azure Devops through SSH, executing a shell script to pull git repo, and build it with ie. vue-cli and Laravel.

When the bash script is executed I receive a lot of errors on nearly all commands although everything is succeeding - can anyone tell me how to get rid of these unless something is really failing (would be nice to fail if npm build exit with code 1 for instance).
See screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: How does your packages.config look like? And what's the result if you run the same npm command in local command-line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be one bug starting from npm `V.3.10.8`. You can check [this discussion](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14042).

[As a workaround](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/14042#issuecomment-251683306) you can add this script to `package.json` and run the command with `--no-optional` switch:

```
"optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "*"
  },
```

Also, there's possibility that your NPM version is too old. You can use [Node.js tool installer task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/node-js?view=azure-devops) with `version spec = 12.x` to install higher node.js and npm versions.

Answer (score 1):

Screenshots are only really helpful for visual issues. You can use PasteBin or etc to share long logs if necessary.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/10125) Azure just follows the lead of whatever shell it's running code in. So, in Bash it continues unless explicitly told to stop.

To easily change this behavior you can add `set -e` (or `set -o errexit`) at the start of your script. The `errexit` option causes Bash to exit as soon as a command/etc returns a non-zero exit code.

Another worthy addition is the `set -o pipefail` option. If you've got any pipes like `command1 | command2` this will return the first non-zero exit code from a chain of pipes of any length as the result. So, if command1 fails above but command2 succeeds it would return the failure code from command1 instead of overwriting it.

Finally, `set -u` (or `-o nounset`) causes an error when unset variables are encountered during parameter expansion. If running in a non-interactive shell, it will also exit.

Many scripts combine these by running `set -euo pipefail` at the beginning to stop them from running after the first problem is encountered.

If you want to explicitly force a bash script to exit you can use `||` and `&&` accordingly. The expression `command || exit` will exit if the command fails and `command && exit` will exit if the command succeeds.